# Issue with getting background image to display full page using Squarespace

Tags: html, css, background-image, squarespace

I have gotten this CSS code to display a background image full page in a Squarespace website I'm working on:

```
#collection-5de6d28545f1a7075b7a2741 #canvas{
  max-width: 100% !important;
 padding-left: 0px !important;
 padding-right: 0px !important;
 padding-top: 11px !important;
 background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5cff45ae4a957c0001a6673b/t/5dc6fcead1c0ab7b9e4f5e60/1573321963518/richie_+5.jpeg)no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

However, in the main Home page of the website the background image is stuck in the upper part of the page. The image is big enough that it can be stretched to fit the whole page. In the preview you get while using the Squarespace editor the code seem to do it's purpose, but once you actually go to the page it's not working because there's a black space taking up most of the screen. Because I'm not very familiar with how Squarespace structures the HTML code for you, I don't know if the issue has to do with my CSS or some HTML element. How can I get the background image to display full page?

**UPDATE**

Using Brandon's suggestion, I manage to get the image to take up the page from top to bottom, however in width there are still black spaces on both sides of the image.

Now I'm using :

```
#collection-5de6d28545f1a7075b7a2741 #canvas{
  background-position: center top !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 11px);
 background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5cff45ae4a957c0001a6673b/t/5dc6fcead1c0ab7b9e4f5e60/1573321963518/richie_+5.jpeg)
}
```

With this CSS I can get the background image to take up almost all the page except there is still a black space on the left side. Also this cas caused the image to be zoomed in, so even thought it is taking the space I want, the image is now zoomed in to one part of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to add below css on the on exisitng website css for canvas

```
#collection-5de6d28545f1a7075b7a2741 #canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: calc(89vh);
    background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5cff45a…/t/5dc6fce…/1573321963518/richie_+5.jpeg);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: none; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your suggestion and now I'm getting a black space on the bottom of the screen. Also it seems the image is still being zoomed in. I updated the page to use your code if you wish to check out what I'm getting now.

Comment: try adding below css at the top of css file
html,body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

Comment: Almost there! Is there a way to fully display the whole image? Right now it is zoomed in and the whole image is not shown.

Comment: you should use image of bigger dimensions and width of image should be greater than height in you case.

Comment: Hmm the image is 1413x1413 so I thought that would work. Does the image have to be higher than that?

Comment: rather than using image of same width and height, try to use image with width greater than height.  This may help you to set mostly complete image on screen. Althogh while working with backgrounds, we should always consider that the portion of image may cut from ends depending upon you background position.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59849784/5338581), you can remedy the issue using the following CSS:

```
#collection-5de6d28545f1a7075b7a2741 #canvas {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 11px);
}
```

See the linked-to answer for an explanation on how it works.

Comment: Yes, I get why i should do this, but even with this line of code I struggle to find the right values I need for the background image to take up the whole page. Right now, using your answer, the background image is not taking up the whole page and I can't find what i should change with padding for the image to display entirely.